# Sqoop not loading CLOB type data into hive table properly

Tags: sqoop

I am  trying to use Sqoop job for importing data from Oracle and one of the column in Oracle table is of data type CLOB which contains newline characters.

In this case, the option `--hive-drop-import-delims` is not working. Hive table doesn’t read the `/n` characters properly.

Please suggest how I can import CLOB data into target directory parsing all the characters properly.